# Need CSS to get this Text to Wrap

Tags: html, css

What do I need to do to get the "title" to wrap in this snippet?  Additionally, when it wraps, it should push the table down.  Below is a picture.  I would like the line starting with **This is the title** to wrap.

[image: Need the Title to Wrap]

I have imported into a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mschenkel/8mqnLcd6/1/)

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ANSI">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>

      #body {
        width:400px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
      }

      #content-1 {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        background:#f7f7f7;
      }

      #wrapper {  bottom:0;overflow: hidden; }
      .tablecontent { z-index: 99;  margin: 10px; padding: 35px 5px 5px 5px;background-color:#FFFFFF;  border: 1px solid; border-color: #B8B8B8; border-radius: 4px;}
      .tabletitle {color: #005c9c;padding-top: 20px;padding-left: 20px;z-index: 100;position:absolute;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","table"]});

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var cssClassNames = {
        'tableCell': 'wrapall'};



        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('string','Country','col1');
        datatable.addColumn('number','Metric 1');
        datatable.addColumn('number','Metric2');
        datatable.addColumn('number','Metric3');
        datatable.addRows(2);
        datatable.setCell(0,0,'United States');
        datatable.setCell(0,1,7);
        datatable.setCell(0,2,306);
        datatable.setCell(0,3,67.32,'67.32%');
        datatable.setCell(1,0,'India');
        datatable.setCell(1,1,5);
        datatable.setCell(1,2,139);
        datatable.setCell(1,3,76.98,'76.98%');

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('dashboardtable_20'));
        table.draw(datatable, {showRowNumber: false, 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames});
      }
    </script>





  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
          <div id="content-1">
            <div class="tabletitle">This is the title of my widget. But I want this to wrap if the title is long.</div>
            <div id="dashboardtable_20" class="tablecontent"></div>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I cant see the table in your fiddle...

Comment: Check now - Sorry, had done fork and didn't save.

Comment: Is this markup doable? http://jsfiddle.net/vqnp75u4/ - Moved .tablecontent styles onto a wrapper which then contains the title and the table. Title can then sit in the 'real' flow of elements rather than absolute, whilst not losing the visuals you seem to be after

Comment: @SmokeyPHP doesn't look like it.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - Yes - that seems to work too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest don't use `position:absolute`, instead try to match the styles from the title and the table like this:

```
.tablecontent {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #B8B8B8;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-top: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.tabletitle {
  color: #005c9c;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #B8B8B8;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

#### [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mqnLcd6/8/)

Comment: @MSchenkel if it was helpful don't forget to mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Remove rule `position: absolute;` from your `.tabletitle`.

Comment: This solves the "wrapping" issue.  BUT - now the contents show above where I am intending them to show.

Answer (score 0):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8mqnLcd6/16/)

```
 .tabletitle {
    color: #005c9c;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    z-index: 100;
    position:absolute;
     margin-right: 80px;
             }
```

i hope this sweet's your needs

Answer (score 0):

I changed your CSS, it's kind of hacky but it keeps the markup the same. I removed `position: absolute` and other unnecessary properties. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mqnLcd6/19/)**.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change position absolute to relative then made the height and width adjustments for the particular div:

```
.tabletitle {
color: #005c9c;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-left: 20px;
z-index: 100;
position: relative;
white-space: normal;
width: 282px;
height: 16px;
top: 27px;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8mqnLcd6/20/